# Binding a DataGrid column to a List<string> (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a DataGrid with three columns :

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="EquipmentArray" Style="{StaticResource DataGridEquipment}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Adress" Binding="{Binding IPAdress}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Connection Type" Binding="{Binding ConnectionType}"/>

    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

`Description` and `IPAdress` are strings, but `ConnectionType` is a `List<string>` since an Equipment can have several connection types for one IP Adress.

The problem is that binding the corresponding column with the `ConnectionType` list just displays "`Collection()`" in my DataGrid and not the values.

I tried changing the `List` for an `ObservableCollection`, without success.

Here is how I am adding the values to my `List<string>` :

```cs
// listEquipments is a List<Equipment> acquired through a function parameter, containing the Description and IP Adress of the Equipments
for (int i = 0; i < listEquipments.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> connections = // query which returns a string list of the Equipments' ConnectionType according to the values in listEquipments
    foreach (string connection in connections )
        listEquipments[i].ConnectionType.Add(connection);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `DataGridTextColumn` it can only display you a `string`. So when you bind it to a `string` property it works just fine. However when you bind a more complex object like `List<string>` the framework cannot understand how it should display a `List<string>` as a `string`. I think what the framework does in this case is to perform the usual `ToString()` operation on the object you bind, hence your `List<string>` instance. This operation will give you the type name of your object, hence a string with `"List<string>"`. I'm a little surprised where the `"Collection()"` comes from, because at least from the code you posted I don't see anything obvious to produce *that* string.

Anyways the solution is that you need to define *how* you want to visually present your list of strings. You need to define this mapping from a list of strings (`List<string>`) to a single `string`. The framework cannot do this automatically for you.

So you have two options:

1. Adapt your viewmodel property to `string ConnectionType`, where you do the transformation from string list to single string in your viewmodel
2. Create a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that does the transformation and make sure to reference that converter in your XAML, so that it gets used

From my experience I would recommend you to go with option 1), because it is easier to understand, easier to test the "whole chain", puts the logic in one place and thus is overall let error prone as you don't need to reply on that converter to "intercept".

Comment: How would you go about implementing option 1)? I just don't know how to do it so that the `ConnectionType` property is different for, let's say 3, exact same IP Adresses and Descriptions.

Comment: It depends on how you want to do the transformation and if it's meaning at all! If so, then you could concatenate the individual strings of a `connectionTypeList` in a property like this `string ConnectionType { get { return string.Join("; ", connectionTypeList); } }`. Again, overall it depends if this makes sense here at all from use case / UI point of view, which I cannot judge here! If it doesn't, then consider using something else then `DataGridTextColumn`.

Comment: I would need to create new DataGridRows with the same `Description` and `IPAdress` but with a different `ConnectionType` for each. Instead of a TextBlock, I tried with a `ListBox` whose ItemsSource I bound to my `List<string>`  and it worked but it didn't create a new row for each string in the list, it just displayed a ListBox with several items for one single row.